# How do I access parameters sent with splat operator alone

Tags: ruby

I am aware that I can use splat operator to pass multiple parameters and access them inside the method.

```
def meth(arg*)
  print arg
end
meth(1,2,'string') #=> [1,2,"string"]
```

But Ruby doesn't complain when creating a method with `splat` operator alone as argument. For instance this method definition does not throw any errors so I take it is valid.  But how do I access the parameters passed?

```
def meth(*)
  #how do I access the parameters passed here.  
  # puts * is obviously invalid
end
```

Comment: I'm just speculating, but this may be the equivalent of using `_` in an argument list to indicate to other devs that you're going to throw away the vars because you don't need them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `*` is for accepting variable number of arguments that are not to be used. The `_` is used to accept a single argument that is not used, but there is a difference. While the first argument received by `_` can be referred to by `_`, the arguments received by `*` cannot be referred to.

```
def foo _, x, _; puts _ end
foo(1, 2, 3) # => 1

def foo *; puts * end # => syntax error
```

Hence, while the use of the initial `_` is a convention to receive arguments that are not to be used, the use of secondary `_` or `*` prevents the arguments received from being used.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question, and one which just came up in an article I read this week.  See this, including comments at the end.  See:

[The strange Ruby Splat](http://endofline.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/the-strange-ruby-splat/)

Alone, it doesn't allow access to the variables but it can protect you from receiving unexpected input.

Answer (score 0):

As an example of my speculations in the comments above:

```
def abc( a, b, * )
  puts a
  puts b
end
# => nil
abc( 1,2,3,4,5,6 )
1
2
# => nil
```